# In a C# application, where does Windows grab the name of process when it appears in the Task Manager?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

When you open the Task Manager in Windows, you see process names.

For any given c# application, how do you set that name?

Comment: Stricktly speaking, there is no such a thing as a process name in Windows. Task manager can display process' image name on 'Process' tab, or application name on the 'Applications' tab, which is merely the title of the process main windows. What precisely do you want to set then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For any given c# application, how do you set that name?

If you're  using Visual Studio, go to the project properties and set the assembly name at the Application tab.

Answer (score 8):

The application name is the title of the form being displayed.

The process name is the name of the executable.

The process description is controlled via the **AssemblyTitle** attribute typically found in *AssemblyInfo.cs*:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Your process description here")].
```